# Using a .NET CF dll in C for WinCE

Tags: mysql, c, windows-ce

I am currently developing a library in C for WinCE to work with Amazon Relational Database Service. These API's will help in managing the Amazon database instance providing functionality like scaling up the size of the database instance.

I also need to provide API's and functionality to use the database. Basically, being able to CONNECT to the database instance and running queries like INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE.

If i do development in C# this becomes easier as a dll for .NET Compact Framework is available providing me the MySQL connector. So i can connect to the Amazon RDS MySQL instance and carry out the various queries. This feature i need to provide in C for WinCE.

The methods i have tried are as follows:

1. Tried to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress. I can load the .NET CF dll but GetProcAddress fails. Tried various string combinations to get address of MySqlConnection. Even if this works (assuming i am doing something wrong currently), i am not sure how to use the object and the methods of MySqlConnection or any other.
2. I found out about hosting CLR. This doesn't seem to work as i can't get the mscoree.dll, mscoree.h or library. One MSDN article mentioned that .NET CF does not support this.
3. The other way mentioned is the use of COM Interop. I have only the .NET CF dll and do not the C# source, so i am not sure if this is what will work. From what i understand, i need to have the source and do something like shown http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738(v=vs.71).aspx here.
4. I tried cross compiling the full MySQL Connector source (the one which is available for Windows platform) using CMake 2.8.11-rc4 as this detects my WinCE6 SDK along with VS2008. The configuration itself fails.

Can anyone suggest possible ways of accomplishing of what i want to do? May be i am looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Did you consider writing a COM visible .Net wrapper?

Comment: I am not that knowledgeable in .NET FW and C#. Can you give some pointers?  <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx>. I came across this. Doesn't seem like what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  What would be required is known as EE Hosting, meaning that native code would have to load and host the execution engine.  The Compact Framework has no support or ability to do this.

You also cannot create a COM component in the Compact Framework for the same reasons.  The COM infrastructure would have no way to load up the managed classes, because it cannot host the EE.

There's simply no way to get native code to call managed code unless managed code was run first, in a managed process.  Basically you'd have to create some sort of proxy executable that would have to run, and the native code would call it via IPC.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html

I wish somebody would have told me about this. Much easier to implement and get the above work done.